# AWS website with only S3 and RDS. Is it possible without EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have a task where I had to check whether if it is possible to serve a secure website where the
content is served out from S3 and dynamic data is served out from RDS.

Is it possible to do this job, or do I need EC2 instances as well?

Thanks for helping me,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible - static assets (html/js/css/images) all stored on s3, cloudfront distribution pointing to your s3 location, an api gateway layer to act as the endpoints for your api calls - those api endpoints call aws lambda functions, and then some custom aws lambda code to perform the actual rds queries - and authentication done by aws cognito.

All this can be done without ec2.